# Install chipset driver before nic driver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

When installing drivers, should I be installing the chipset drivers first, or doesn't it matter?  i.e. can I jump straight to the nic driver?

Comment: Windows should automatically install the device drivers when the device is detected.

Comment: Through experience it shouldn't matter. @Ramhound - What if Windows doesn't have the driver in its store to begin with, especially if you have no network connectivity to download from Windows Update...

Comment: The obvious answer is if Windows is not aware of the driver. It will ask the user for the driver then automatically install the driver.  99% of network devices will work with the default lan device driver.

Comment: @Ramhound, windows 7 didn't detect the nic driver at all.  for the gc, it just installed a generic driver which only allows a resolution of 640x480.

Comment: I was speaking of the network driver, the chipset driver , is another story.  In any case just providing windows the driver is enough the order really isn't important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows 98 ages... Yes. Especially the chipset has onboard nic.
Now it doesn't matter. But I still prefer to install the chipset driver first.

Sometimes, it is more important to install chipset driver with integrated graphics device before you install individual graphic card driver.

Comment: Aye, old habits die hard.  Glad to see someone here who knows old hardware but doesn't perpetuate out-of-date knowledge that is so commonplace.